# Regex find group if suffix exists

Tags: regex

I have next pattern of Regex: `a(.)ad.*cc(\d)`
and 2 examples of input string: **"a7ad==cc0"** and **"a7a==cc0"**

I'm getting **'7'**, **'0'** in first case and **none**, **none** in second

But I want  **'7'**, **'0'** in first case and **none**, **'0'** in second
(first group must be found if has d-suffix only)

Comment: Intersting, why you don't write literal `==` in your pattern?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Seeing as this looks like variables, it should probably match `[SPACE]=[SPACE]`, `<=`, `===`, `!=` etc. as well.

Comment: Probably, but I want to be sure. Finally it's not so important!

Comment: @ I used these symbols '==' to simplify the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
(?:a(.)ad)?.*cc(\d)
```

where `(?:a(.)ad)?` makes an attempt to match `a7ad`, if it matches, it capture the number in group 1, else the group 1 is empty.

Comment: Do you really mean `(?=a(.)ad)?` and not `(?:a(.)ad)?` An optional lookahead makes not much sense to me.

Comment: I tried it, both is working on rubular.com, but I think the non capturing group is better to understand than an optional lookahead assertion.

Comment: @stema: I also tried both, they work. But I agree with you on the understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```
a(?:(.)ad|.a).*cc(\d)
```

If the first alternative `(.)ad` fails, the regex engine use the second alternative `.a` and the first capturing group returns `None`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a group optional with ?.

If `ad` is optional in the left param, do:

```
a(.)(?:ad)?.*cc(\d)
```

(optional non-captured group)

If only `d` i s optional, you can do:

```
a(.)ad?.*cc(\d)
```

(just make `d`optional)

I'd also use the fact that there is `==` (if it always comes in between the parts which are important to you). In which way exactly, depends on what kind of input can appear there.